# Rundll32 load order problem

Tags: c++, deployment

My product consists of two dlls (A.dll and B.dll for clarity), A.dll depends on B.dll. Both A and B dlls are in the same folder (say c:\app). At the same time old version of B.dll is in Windows\System32 folder. When I try to run following command from command prompt (current folder is c:\app):

```
rundll32.exe "c:\app\A.dll",DoWork
```

I receive error because rundll32 uses old version of B.dll from System32 folder. I tried to use SetDllDirectory API from DllMain function of A.dll library to add c:\app folder to the search path but it doesn't work for me.
I can't find any useful and complete information about rundll32 internals or any information about dll loading order.
Is it possible to execute rundll32 successfuly in this deployment configuration? (I mean load new B.dll version from c:\app folder).

Comment: It seems I found the solution. I've added /DELAYLOAD:"B.dll" switch to the linker options in A.dll project. After that trick with SetDllDicrectory API begin to work and rundll32 loads new version of B.dll from c:\app folder. Thank you folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### DLL Hell on SO

Well, it's kind of cool in a retro sort of way. Here is a thought: try copying rundll32.exe into the same folder as the new dll's and your product, and run it from there. It might work...

Comment: Yes, it works. But it's too heavy solution from my point of view. It would be perfect if I could execute rundll32.exe from its original folder.

Comment: Additional nastyness: When the next SP is released and System32\Rundll32.EXE is updated, your copy will become outdated and may fail in many "interesting" ways. And I'd hope virusscanners would also consider it suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the old Dll, or use another name for the new dll. Having two versions of something that is supposed to do the same, and giving it the same name, is likely to cause havoc.

Comment: The whole point of DLL's is that you can have a default one. Then as newer ones are released you use the same name so that old code picks up the newer version. But if there is an incompatibility you can still use the old one. Unfortunately it led to a whole series of other problems known as "DLL Hell"

Comment: Exactly, it is DLL Hell. B.dll is legacy component which can't be renamed.